# Covariance between integral of brownian motion and brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, covariance, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let

$$
I = \int_0^1W_tdt,
$$

where $W_t$ is a Brownian motion.
From [Integral of Brownian motion w.r.t. time](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time?newreg=2b8ba41a6572435ea818f95678e3d1c8) we have that

$$
\mathbb{E}[I]=0,
$$
by Fubini's theorem. And that
$$
\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[I] = \mathbb{E}[I^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^1\int_0^1W_sW_tdsdt\right] = \int_0^1\int_0^1\mathbb{E}[W_sW_t]dsdt = \frac{1}{3}.
$$
Here I do not understand how we are able to bring the expectation into the integral, Ito isometry says that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^tX_sdW_s\right)^2\right] = \int_0^t\mathbb{E}[X_s^2]ds
$$
so I am unsure how it is possible to use this here?

Furthermore, I am required to find
$$
\mathbb{C}\text{ov}[I, W_1],
$$

I know that
$$
\mathbb{C}\text{ov}[I, W_1] = \mathbb{E}[IW_1],
$$
since $\mathbb{E}[I] = \mathbb{E}[W_1] = 0$,
my best guess here is then that
$$
\mathbb{E}[IW_1] = \min\left(\frac{1}{3},1\right) = \frac{1}{3},
$$
however, this is probably wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The variance calculation is also an application of Fubini's theorem. And $\Bbb E[IW_1]$ can likewise be handled using Fubini.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you, I understand the first bit now. Still unsure on how to set up $\mathbb{E}[IW_1]$, if you have any hints?

Comment: By Fubini, $\Bbb E[IW_1] =\int_0^1\Bbb E[W_tW_1] dt$.